# Switch between Wifi hotspot and wifi network

Tags: wireless, ap-hotspot

In my work I connect the ethernet by cable and share the internet with my mobile phone through an hotspot wifi connection. However when I'm at home I need to delete the wifi hotspot connection so I can use my wifi network. Is there a way of automatically switch from the hotspot connection to my home wifi network when I arrive home?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of an automatic way, but you should be able to click on the wifi symbol and choose your home wifi when you are at home which in turn will disable your hotspot.

Comment: No you aren't. As long as the hotspot is on you don't get a list of other networks. And I found no way of shutting it of but to delete it. The other way has the same problem as long as there is one known network. It will connect to it and there is no hotspot in the list to choose.